# How to solve multiple warehouse and multiple destination with time cost

Tags: algorithm

there are 3 warehouses A,B,C
each warehouse have drones, and drone ship only one item at a time
warehouse A have 20 drones
warehouse B have 25 drones
warehouse C have 15 drones
there are 100 orders should be processed
and each order destination is one of 5;
delivery time(minute) from warehouse to destination is following

 
      1    2     3     4      5
A    10    25    30    50     60
B    20    10    20    40     55
C    60    40    25    15     20

 
optimize to get total minimum delivery time

Comment: Share what you have tried. We won't do it for you, we will help you in pointing in the right direction.

Comment: This can be reduced to a Network Flow Problem, read more about it.

Comment: I'm not kdding, but I have really no idea about this topic, anyway thanks @AmitKumar I will read about network flow, though I'm not sure how it can be reduced to network flow problem yet

Comment: http://www.optaplanner.org/learn/useCases/vehicleRoutingProblem.html  might help.